# how i need place arg in code for funtion send?

Tags: go, cryptography, smartcontracts, bsc

i have there function:

```
function send(address to, Pair721[] memory tokens) public nonReentrant whenNotPaused {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        Pair721 memory p = tokens[i];
        p.token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, to, p.tokenId);
    }
}
```

and i have code on Golang and i need to create function but i receive this error:

field arg0 for tuple not found in the given struct

how do I need to pass arguments?

i trying every but i dont can....

Comment: This question needs to be better scoped, and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) created. It's not clear what's actually being asked.

Comment: i have 

funcSend = w3.MustNewFunc("send(address, (address,uint256)[])", "bool")

and i have tx 

 tokentx := types.LegacyTx{Value: w3.Big0, To: &contractAddress, Nonce: accountNonce, Data: input, GasPrice: defGasPrice}

and i need

Comment: Feel free to edit the question with a complete, minimal example of what you need to do. Try not to put a bunch of code in a comment as it doesn't format well.